# One more citation problem (natbib)

Tags: citing, babel

I have been trying to get my citation to work for few hours, and I am currently out of ideas.
I am not mixing up babel and biblatex (at least not so I notice).

```
% Bibliography

\usepackage[sort&compress,authoryear]{natbib} % Uncoment if you want to used NatBib instead of BibLaTeX (and comment the bitlatex line below)

% \usepackage{biblatex}  % BibLaTeX used for references. 
\usepackage{csquotes} % BibLaTex wants to have context sensitive quotes
%\addbibresource{references.bib} %  Name of *.bib file containing references
```

I have tried both citation packages, and both do not work. I do/should have newest biber package installed (I am on Arch based system).
My `references.bib` is in the same folder.
However, the pdf (or code) does not compile if I add

```
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{references}
```

to the bottom of the file.
If I add these two lines, I get these errors when using babel:

```
natbib: Citation 'reference' on page X undefined
```

for all of the citations in my reference.
If I skip bibliography commands at the bottom, the pdf does compile but I get `?` instead of reference number.

I think this is a version incompatibility, because I fired up an old `tex` file with references, which I wrote 2 years ago, and I know work, but I am getting the same errors.
I don't know which compatibility to check or how to check it.

The old `tex` file that did work few months ago

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,BCOR=10mm]{scrbook}

% Packages
%\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[icelandic, english]{babel}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
%\usepackage{enumerate,color}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
%\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
%\usepackage[sf,normalsize]{subfigure}
\usepackage[format=plain,labelformat=simple,labelsep=colon]{caption}
%\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {pictures/} }
\usepackage{subfig}
% Configurations
%\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}

\title{VÉL103M - Töluleg Burðarþolsgreining}
\subtitle{Greining á hillukerfi}
\author{Ólafur Víðir Guðbjargarson}
\date{29 Nóvember 2021}

\begin{document}
    
    \maketitle
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables
    
    \chapter{Inngangur}
    Þessi ritgerð fjallar um greiningu á færslum og spennu í hillu kerfum, sem má finna til dæmis heima hjá okkur og í Costco. Hillur eru notaðar á nánast hverju heimili og fyrirtækjum og eru stundum sér hannaðar, eins og til dæmis til að halda lager. Verkefnið er hluti af kynninga verkefni í VÉL103M - Töluleg Burðarþolsfræði í Háskóla Íslands, og var gert til að auka skilning á því hvernig álag á hillur hefur áhrif á undirstöður. Leitast verður eftir að uppfylla eftirfarandi markmið:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Æfa hönnun bitavirkis
        \item Auka færni í greiningu
        \item Meta færslur, undirstöðukrafta og vægi
    \end{itemize}
Hönnuð var einfalt hillukerfi í Ansys, álag sett á hillurnar og forritið látið reikna út færslur, undirstöðukrafta og vægi. Yfirleitt eru útreikningar fyrir hillukerfi gert í tveim þrepum. Fyrst er kerfið greint í tvívíðu módeli í tölvu, en einstaka hlutir eru greindir í þrívídd. Seinna skrefið er að sannreina niðurstöður, en þá er afmyndun og spenna í kerfinu sannreind í hillukerfinu \cite{meca}. Mynd 1.1 sýnir hefðbundið hillukerfi hjá Costco og þeim fyrirtækjum sem halda lager.
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \subfloat[\centering Uppsetning á hillukerfi]{{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{meca}}}
    \qquad
    \subfloat[\centering Hillukerfi hámarka plássnýtingu]{{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{meca2}}}
    \caption{Lager hillukerfi}
    \label{fig: Lager}
\end{figure}
    \chapter{Bakgrunnur/fræði}
    Tilgangur verkefnisins var að skoða álag, spennur og færslur í hillukerfi þegar álag er sett á hillurnar. Kröfur sem eru gerðar til hillukerfa eru skráðar samkvæmt leiðbeiningum Evrópska \textbf{EN 15512} staðlinum. Hillukerfin eru oftast úr þunnu, kald-dregnu stáli \cite{meca}.  \\ 
    Ákveðið var að minnka hillukerfið mikið og setja minni kraft á hillurnar til að einfalda teikningar í tölvuforritum. Til að teikna og greina hillukerfið var notast við Ansys. Ekki var gerð greining á mismunandi festingamöguleikum fyrir hillukerfi. \\ 
    Upprunalega átti að bera saman niðurstöður úr Ansys og FreeCAD, en það gekk ekki eftir þar sem ekki náðist að gera net fyrir hillukerfið í FreeCAD. \\
    Hillur og hillukerfi eru hannaðar til að hámarka geymslunýtingu á hlutum, og er notkun þeirra allt frá því að vera einföld bókahilla yfir í stæður fyrir geymslu á brettum. Hönnun á brettastæðum er þannig þyngd efnist í stæðunni er sjaldan yfir 5\% af þyngd þess sem þær bera \cite{meca}. \\
    Fjöldi elementa var gefin skýrslu úr Ansys og má sjá í töflu 1.1
    \begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \sffamily
    \caption*{Fjöldi elementa}
    \begin{tabular}{||*{2}{c||}}
    \hline
    \bfseries Fjöldi nóda & 178 \\
    \bfseries Fjöldi snerti elementa & 60 \\
    \bfseries Fjöldi fastra elementa & 90 \\
    \bfseries Heildarfjöldi elementa & 150 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Fjöldi elementa og nóda í kerfinu}
    \label{table: Element}
    \end{table}
    \chapter{Aðferðahluti}
    Hillur og hillukerfi eru notuð út um allt og þótt að hönnun þeirra sé mismunandi, er notkun þeirra ávallt sú sama, að geyma hluti og hámarka nýtingu á plássi.
    Verkefnið var teiknað upp í Ansys 19.2. Teiknaðar voru tvær lóðréttar línur með tveggja metra bili á milli þeirra, og fjórar línur þvert á milli. Efsta línan var á toppi lóðréttu línana. Hinar þrjár voru teiknaðar á hálfs metra millibili niður. Mynd 3.1 sýnir uppsetningu sem notast var við. Athugið, að Mynd 3.1 er teiknuð í FreeCAD, en uppsetningin er sú sama og var notuð í Ansys. Ansys var síðan notað til að búa til prófíla úr línunum.Þversnið á undirstöðum má sjá á mynd 3.2, en notast var við 10 cm breiðan prófíl sem var 1 cm á breidd, á meðan þversnið fyrir hillur er hringlótt með þvermál upp á 1 cm. Ekki var farið í það að hanna nákvæma samsetninga búnað til að spara tíma.
    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{uppsetning}
        \caption{Uppsetning hillukerfis}
        \label{fig: Uppsetning}
    \end{figure}
Elementin voru 6 með undirstöðum og þar sem að þetta er tiltölulega einfaldur hlutur, þá var ekki breytt þéttleika netsins. Þétting í þessu verkefni lengir tíma í útreikninga en munurinn á niðurstöðum er innan 2\% skekkjumarka. 
Álagið á hillurnar var ákveðið að væri $ 1500 \ N/m$ á neðstu hilluna, $1350 \ N/m$ á næstu hillu fyrir ofan. Efstu tvær hillurnar voru látnar vera með $1150 \ N/m$ álag. Öll þessi álög eru nálægt hámarks álagi á hefðbundið bílskúrs hillukerfi, sem er 250 kg á hillu. Efnið sem var valið í þessari greiningu var venjulegt svart stál (Structual Steel). Eðliseiginleikar þess sem gefnir eru upp í Ansys má sjá í töflu 3.1. \\
\clearpage
    \begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \subfloat[\centering Þversnið undirstaða]{{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{snid}}}
    \qquad
    \subfloat[\centering Þversnið hilla]{{\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{hillu_snid}}}
    \caption{Þversnið undirstaða og hilla}
    \label{fig: Undirstöður}
\end{figure} 
\begin{table}
\centering
\sffamily
\caption*{\textbf{Eðliseiginleikar}}
\begin{tabular}{||*{2}{c||}} 
 \hline
 \bfseries Þéttleiki & $7.850 \ kg/m^3$ \\ 
 \bfseries Fjaðurstuðull & $200 \ GPa$ \\
 \bfseries Poisson hlutfall & $0.3$ \\
 \bfseries Togþol & $250 \ MPa$ \\
 \bfseries Hámarks togþol & $460 \ MPa$ \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Eðliseiginleikar stáls}
\label{table: Eðliseiginleikar}
\end{table}

\clearpage
    \chapter{Niðustöður}
    Skoðaðar voru heildar færslur, sem hefur áhrif á það hvernig hillurnar geta afmyndast þegar álag er sett á þær. Undirstöðukraftar voru einnig skoðaðir, eins og hvernig vægi myndi haga sér í kerfinu. \\
    Þar sem álagið var mismunandi á hillu var færslan á hillunum mismunandi, en mynd 4.1 sýnir hvernig neðsta hillan er með tæplega $4 \ cm$ færslu. Munurinn á efstu og neðstu hillunni er næstum því sentimetri. Miðað við öryggiskröfur Mecalux, þá þarf sveigjan í hillubita að ná 20\% af lengd bitans til að vera dæmdur ónýtur \cite{meca2}. Ef að þetta væri hilla, sem væri fest á milli tveggja hillubita, þá væri afmyndunin yfir 20\% og hillan því dæmd ónýt.
    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{total_deform}
        \caption{Heildar afmyndun á hillum}
        \label{fig: Total deformation}
    \end{figure} \\
Með því að skoða í stefnuaflögun fáum við sömu niðurstöður og í heildar aflögun, nema að tölurnar eru neikvæðar til að sýna færslu niður.  en mynd 4.2 sýnir hvernig Ansys túlkar stefnuaflögun. Færslur á hillum eru þær sömu og í fyrri mynd. Lang minnsta færslan er í undirstöðunum í kerfinu, enda er hönnunin þannig að þær standist allt það álag sem sett er á hillurnar, innan öryggissviðmiða. \\
\clearpage
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{directional_deform}
    \caption{Stefnuaflögun sýnir sama og heildar aflögun}
    \label{fig: Directional deformation}
\end{figure}
Mótvægið á stoðunum var skoðað, til að sjá hvernig það hagaði sér, ásamt því að athuga hvort að eitthvað vægi væri í kerfinu. Mótvægið er undir smá horni, í stað þess að vera lóðrétt, þar sem að hillurnar er á milli tveggja undirstaða. Mynd 4.3 sýnir hvernig mótstaðan hegðar sér og hvaða kraftar eru í kerfinu. Átt mótvægis er eðlileg þar sem að hillurnar draga undirstöður niður þeim megin sem þær eru festar. 
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \subfloat[\centering Mótvægi í kerfinu]{{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{Force_reaction}}}
    \qquad
    \subfloat[\centering Kraftar í mótvægi]{{\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{Force_reaction_table}}}
    \caption{Hegðun mótvægis}
    \label{fig: Mótvægi}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
Vægið í kerfinu er ekki mikið og liggur í átt að okkur á z-ás eins og sést á mynd 4.4. Þar sem álagið er niður í y-ás, ætti vægið að vera á x-ás á löppunum, það er að segja það ætti að vera smá súningur til hægri á vinstri stoð, og til vinstri á hægri stoð. 
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \subfloat[\centering Vægi í kerfinu]{{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{moment_reaction}}}
    \qquad
    \subfloat[\centering Kraftar í væginu]{{\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{moment_reaction_table}}}
    \caption{Hegðun vægis}
    \label{fig: Vægi}
\end{figure}
Spennur voru reiknaðar og má sjá niðurstöður fyrir spennur í fyrir hvert álag í töflu 4.2, og voru þær voru fundnar með jöfnu 4.1. Spennurnar eru niður á við þar sem öll færsla er niður.
\begin{equation}
    \sigma = \frac{F}{A}
\end{equation}
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \sffamily
    \caption*{\textbf{Reiknaðar spennur í hillum}}
    \begin{tabular}{||*{2}{l||}}
        \hline
        \bfseries Spennur í efstu tveim hillum & 29.3 MPa \\
        \hline
        \bfseries Spenna í næst neðstu hillu & 34.4 MPa \\
        \hline
        \bfseries Spenna í neðstu hillu & 38.2 MPa \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\caption{Spennur í hillum}
\label{table: Spenna}
\end{table}
Hillurnar aflagast mikið miðað við það álag sem sett er á þær og er ástæðan sú að hillurnar hafa bara 1 cm þvermál. Spennurnar í hillunum eru hinsvegar langt fyrir neðan fjaðurstuðul efnisins og fyrir neðan skurðfjaðurstuðul (Shear modulus of elasticity) efnisins \cite{mom}. 
    \chapter{Samantekt}
    Miðað við hönnun eru færslurnar í hillu elementunum mjög miklar í Ansys. Ástæðan er sú að kerfið er hannað í tvívídd og þversnið hillanna er mjög lítið, eða 1 cm. Bil á milli undirstaða hefur líka áhrif, en fyrir svona þunnar hillubita, þá er 2 m bil í það lengsta fyrir þetta kerfi. \\ 
    Ekki var ástæða til að gera netið fínna, þar sem að það hefur takmörkuð áhrif á niðurstöðurnar á meðan það hefur mikil áhrif á reikningstíma. Ekki var athugað hvort að stærra net hefði einhver áhrif á niðurstöður og reikningstíma þar sem að það tók tölvuna um mínútu að reikna staðlað net. Hættan með stærra net er sú að skekkjur í niðurstöðum verða stærri og óáræðanlegri. \\
    Miðað við öryggisblöð frá Mecalux, eru færslurnar í hillu elementunum innan öryggisstaðla. 
    \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
    \bibliography{Heimildaskra.bib}
\end{document}
```

Edit: 20 th. Feb 2023
So after messing a bit with this problem of mine, I created very simple document and a  `ref.bib` file. The document is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\title{A Short Guide to Reference Management using natbib with BibTeX}
\author{CiteDrive}
\date {January 1988}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\textbf{Narrative citation:} \citet{Doe:1966} investigated the risks of incorrectly \\
recorded [...], which results in distortion.
\textbf{Parenthetical citation:} The risks of incorrect recording of [...] could lead to distortion
\citep{Doe:1966}.

\medskip


\bibliography{ref}

\end{document}
```

This works wonderfully, but my other will not compile at all. Not sure why.

Comment: Welcime on tex sx. AFAIK `ieeetr` is a (unsorted) numeric bibtex style,  hence incompatible with the author year option of  `natbib` If you want make it working in (unsorted) athoryear mode you could switch to `IEEEtranN` style. Have a look at https://www.bibtex.com/s/bibliography-style-ieeetran-ieeetrann/

Comment: Do I need to delete `aux` and `log` files for it to work? My next question is why this why was I able to compile my old `tex` file with exact same command just 3 - 4 months ago? I am really trying to understand why it doesn't work this time around.

Comment: @Jhor I changed the `ieeetr` to `IEEEtranN` and I am still getting the same errors even after deleting aux and log files. It is super weird to me that when I put in `\bibliographystyle{}` I only get three styles from the suggestion tree. `abbrv`, `alpha` and `plain`. Feels like I am missing some package somewhere.

Comment: Please, make a minimal compilable example showing the issue. From those snippets of code it's hard to tell what could be wrong, except that you need to use a bibstyle compatible with `natbib`.

Comment: @egreg How would I do that? Could I upload both here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, finally got citation working.
Moved from `natbib` to `biblatex`.

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
```

I have no idea why this works, but it is giving me references now, and I am happy :D

Comment: Probably won't resolve your original question but you might want to take a look at [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/106162)

Comment: I actually had seen this. But thank you. I still have much to learn.